# DocuSign removes other signatures

Tags: docusignapi

After signing the document with DocuSign other signatures (not from DocuSign) they turn into plain text (you cannot see them in the signature panel in Adobe Acrobat Reader). Anyone know such a problem?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more about using docusign vs programming against it

Answer (score 2):

In order to preserve pre-existing digital signatures, your DocuSign account and envelope must be configured as follows:

1. the account must have the DocuSign Standards Based Signatures feature (SBS) for digital signature support.
2. "Lock documents with platform signature for SBS envelope" - disabled
3. can only add a signHere tab
4. No Demo watermark (ok for Production)
5. Envelope ID - no imprinting

You will need Customer Support to implement some of these changes.  You may also need to upgrade your account type.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're referring to X.509 standards-based digital signatures.

By default, DocuSign uses electronic signatures. I believe that if you configure your DocuSign signature request (the envelope) to require standards-based digital signatures, then existing digital signatures on the documents will be preserved.